# Apache Directory Directives

Tags: apache

Apache default installation comes with

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all allow
</Directory>
```

Question 1 : This is the root directory right ?

Let's say we used the DocumentRoot parameter

```
DocumentRoot "/etc/html/test"
```

Question 2 : does the DocumentRoot parameter eliminates the "/" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, '/' would point to the root directory of file system. Normally the Directory stanza for the root directory would deny all access by default, e.g.:

```
# Deny access to all files on the server's filesystem.
<Directory />
  AllowOverride none
  Require all denied
</Directory>
```

You would then permit access to specific directories that httpd should have access to. For example, the server's DocumentRoot:

```
Define DOCROOT "/var/www/httpd/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "${DOCROOT}"
<Directory "${DOCROOT}">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None

  #
  # Allow access to resources in the server's DocumentRoot.
  #
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: so by looking to this config `<Directory />
  Require all granted
</Directory>` `<Directory "${DOCROOT}">
  Require all granted
</Directory>` this means that an attacker that has access to the DocRoot can go back using the path to access to the root directory right ?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible for any user to access any file on your file system if you have `Require all granted` on the root file system.